# Push notification custom sound not working - Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I trying to add custom sound for push notification using Ionic 6 & Angular.

In the below code, I"m getting the device token & storing in firebase DB.

```
if (isPushNotificationsAvailable) {
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
        if (result.receive === 'granted') {
            PushNotifications.register();
        }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
        this.token = token.value;
        const tokenRef = ref(db, `deviceToken/${this.token}`);
        set(tokenRef, this.token);
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        //  this.router.navigateByUrl('/new-bookings')
    });
}
```

I've created a cloud function to trigger the notification below is the code,

```
app.post('/sendNotification', function (req, res) {
  let deviceTokens = [];

  admin.database().ref('deviceToken').on("value", snap => {
    let data = snap.val();
    if (data) {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        if (data[key]) {
          deviceTokens.push(data[key]);
        }
      });
      console.log(deviceTokens);

      let notification = {
        "registration_ids": deviceTokens,
        "collapse_key": "type_a",
        "notification": {
          "body": req.body.desc,
          "title": req.body.title,
          // "icon": 'https://images.ctfassets.net/509kpi6dw56l/1CD2g1XQpaJjEzSh2xFnOp/8cb418adda4fd4caad135ebb2056f72a/icon1.png',
          // "sound": 'https://assets.ctfassets.net/509kpi6dw56l/7aYHya51vKNWFgPmm63RfG/772d1b53496f76eec97252b0d9511e11/Alert.mp3'
        }
      };

      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        body: notification,
        json: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Key'
        }
      }

      request(options).then(function (response) {
        res.status(200).json(response);
      })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
  })


});`
```

I get the notification but not with custom sound & icon. I've added the below links in my AndroidManifest.xml still no use.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/icon1" /> <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_sound" android:resource="@raw/alert_sound" />
```

I've referred few others pages & tried but nothing works. Please help what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path of the drawable resource in the `icon`. For the `sound`, you have to put it in */res/raw/*.